# How to convert a formula to discrete values in wolfram-alpha?

Tags: wolfram-alpha

I don't know where this question fits, whether it is the right place...

I plotted the Logistic Function $y=\frac{0.8}{1 + e^{-(x-6)}}$ using [wolframalpha, here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3D0.8%2F(1%2Be%5E(-1*(x-6)))).

Now I want to make it discrete, so I can copy it to excel and make a plot. I want to split the range, let's say, to 20 elements.

(so one column in Excel holds 20 $x$ values, and another column holds 20 times the "computed" formula, dragged down 20 cells, as is customary in Excel...)

Is there a simple way to do it via wolframalpha, rather than mastering Mathematica now?

Comment: You're trying to get discrete value of the points? Which x-values do you want?

Comment: @Moo This is not a graph of a discrete function.

Comment: @TiwaAina, yes, I want the graph to start from $x=0$ and end where $y=0.8$ (which is basically where $x=10$, so if I can't use the $y$ value, I can suffice with the $x$)

Comment: you can use the command `Table[{x,0.8/(1+e^(-(x-6)))},{x,0,10,0.5}]` on WA to get a list of 21 pairs of $(x,y)$ (the 4th parameter in 2nd argument is the step).

Comment: @achillehui: that's it :-) post an answer so I could accept it. Thanks!